# File Upload and display file name in table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm saying apology to ask this repeated Question.

I've tried so many examples for file Uploading finally I wrote the code below.

Once Hyperlink was clicked it is asking file then we select file.

But i want to display the file name in Table , I'm unable to show on table.

```
  <div class="sf_coursehead">
    Upload FileList <a href="#" class="addnew">+ Add New</a> 
           <input type="file" id="upload_input" name="courseAgenda" style="font-size: 50px;
 width: 120px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity :0); position: relative; top: -40px;; left: -20px" />
  </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But how to show selected files in table,that means each selection table will be add `new row`

So please help me to display file name in table,

give me suggestion.
Edit:
this is also not working..

```
$("#upload_input").change(function(){
    var filename = document.getElementById('id_transactions').val();
    alert(filename);
});
```

Comment: before saving into the table what is the content you are getting, can you show that..!

Comment: Actually i'm using java program, when we click +AddNew hyperlink it is asking file and select file and click submit button file will be storing to Folder... All are working perfect but i want to display file name in the table only for user identification..

Comment: From what I can see, I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to do without any use of server-side code, or AJAX code (should you wish for things to happen locally without the entire page posting back).  Do you fully understand what is required when uploading a file?

Comment: for ex: mailing system when we add some attachment first of all showing all uploaded attachment because user may want to delete some attachments. so in that time no need to talking of server thing, first we want to display all the upload things later we worry about server side code, so i'm just trying to display file name in table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Working Code..

```
    <img src="resources/images/profile_image.png" alt="Profile Image"
    width="120" height="150" class="prif_img" />
    <a href="#" class="addnew">NewImage</a> 
<input type="file" id="upload_input" name="courseAgenda"
style="font-size: 50px; width: 120px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity : 0); position: relative; top: -40px;; left: -20px" onchange="uploadFile_onChange(this);" />
```

Script:

```
function uploadFile_onChange(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('.prif_img').attr('src', e.target.result).width(120).height(150);


        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may what you need,

```
<script> 

  $(document).ready(function() {

 
  $("#upload_input").change(function() {  

     var file_name=$("#upload_input").val(); 
     $("#list_files").append("`<tr><td>`"+file_name+"`</td></tr>`');
 

 }); });
 
 </script>
 
 
 </head> <body>
 
 
 <table id="list_files">    </table>
```